# PHP curl very slow, cURL from shell is very fast

Tags: php, performance, shell, curl

For some reason php curl_exec() is very slow. I've narrowed it down to the "starttransfer_time" as displayed by the curl_getinfo() method call:

```
[url] => https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com/
[content_type] => text/namevalue
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 151
[request_size] => 272
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 34.139412
[namelookup_time] => 0.040742
[connect_time] => 0.085858
[pretransfer_time] => 0.205325
[size_upload] => 135
[size_download] => 200
[speed_download] => 5
[speed_upload] => 3
[download_content_length] => 200
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 34.139382
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] =>
[primary_ip] => 173.0.82.163
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )
```

But, I can't seem to figure out what's causing the long starttransfer_time. name lookup, connect and pretransfer are all very reasonable. I've tried tweaking the DNS stuff, IPV4 over IPV6, etc..

I've looked around and googled, but nothing has helped me so far to resolve this. If I try the same curl command directly from the shell, it's fast...fractions of seconds. Nothing like the ~30 seconds as shown above.

here's my setup:

```
define('URL', 'https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com');
$ch = curl_init(URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Anyone have any clue what's up here?

Comment: Is it any better to a different https site, and what about plain http?  Is the cURL version in PHP different from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually related to the Payflow gateway. For some reason my credentials are resulting in very slow transactions.

I tried another set of credentials and it was screaming fast...so...